# Fastest way for multiplying a matrix to a vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix `mat` and a vector `v`. I would like to multiply first column of matrix `mat`by first element of vector `v` and multiply the second column of matrix `mat` by second element of vector `v`. I can do it as shown. How can I do this faster in R since we get a big matrix?

```
    mat = matrix(rnorm(1500000), ncol= 100)
    v= rnorm(100)
    > system.time( mat %*% diag(v))
      user  system elapsed 
      0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: That must be a mighty big matrix you have given the `0.02` elapsed time for 1.5M values.

Comment: Oddly, this is basically a duplicate of your older question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17080099/489704). `:o`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sweep` seems to run a bit faster on my machine

```
sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*")
```

Some benchmarks:

```
> microbenchmark(mat %*% diag(v),sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*"))

Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq   median        uq      max neval
   %*% 214.66700 226.95551 231.2366 255.78493 349.1911   100
 sweep  42.42987  44.72254  62.9990  70.87403 127.2869   100
```

Comment: Why I use your command, it is slower than my code? system.time(sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.02    0.08

Comment: @rose For me ```sweep``` is faster in R under OSX but slower under ubuntu. In general, I think you are going to struggle to improve much on ```%*%``` because it is implemented directly in C (line 610 of src/main/array.c). I suppose you could remove some of the sanity checking from that function but the gains are likely to be very small.

Comment: @orizon Interesting - The results are the same for me (faster on OSX but slower on Ubuntu/Mint).  I was actually surprised when sweep was faster when using my wife's Mac.

Answer (score 14):

Recycling can make it faster but you recycle within columns, not across, so just transpose and transpose back.

```
t( t(mat) * v )
```

This should be faster than `sweep` or `%*%`.

```
microbenchmark(mat %*% diag(v),sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*"), t(t(mat)*v))
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
             %*% 150.47301 152.16306 153.17379 161.75416 281.3315   100
           sweep  35.94029  42.67210  45.53666  48.07468 168.3728   100
   t(t(mat) * v)  16.50813  23.41549  26.31602  29.44008 160.1651   100
```

Answer (score 11):

A bit late to the game, but did someone say *fastest*?! This could be another good use of `Rcpp`. This function (called `mmult`) will by default multiply each column of a matrix by each successive element of a vector, but has the option to do this by column, by setting `byrow = FALSE`. It also checks that `m` and `v` are of an appropriate size given the `byrow` option. Anyway, it's ***fast*** (around 10-12 times quicker than the best native R answer)...

#### EDIT

[**@chris**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2628508/chris) provided [**this great answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405580/1478381) to another question I posed trying to get this to work with `RcppArmadillo`. However it seems that the `Rcpp`-only function I posted here is still around 8 times quicker than that, and around 70 times quicker than the OP method. Click the link for the code for @chris' function - it's beautifully simple.

I'll put the benchmarking at the top..

```
require( microbenchmark )
m <- microbenchmark( mat %*% diag(v) , mmult( mat , v ) , sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*") , chris( mat , v ) , t( t(mat) * v ) , times = 100L )
print( m , "relative" , order = "median" , digits = 3 )
Unit: relative
                        expr   min    lq median    uq   max neval
               mmult(mat, v)  1.00  1.00   1.00  1.00  1.00   100
               chris(mat, v) 10.74  9.31   8.15  7.27 10.44   100
               t(t(mat) * v)  9.65  8.75   8.30 15.33  9.52   100
 sweep(mat, 2, v, FUN = "*") 20.51 18.35  22.18 21.39 16.94   100
             mat %*% diag(v) 80.44 70.11  73.12 70.68 54.96   100
```

Browse on to see how `mmult` works and returns the same result as OP...

```
require( Rcpp )

#  Source code for our function
func <- 'NumericMatrix mmult( NumericMatrix m , NumericVector v , bool byrow = true ){
  if( byrow );
    if( ! m.nrow() == v.size() ) stop("Non-conformable arrays") ;
  if( ! byrow );
    if( ! m.ncol() == v.size() ) stop("Non-conformable arrays") ;

  NumericMatrix out(m) ;

  if( byrow ){
    for (int j = 0; j < m.ncol(); j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < m.nrow(); i++) {
        out(i,j) = m(i,j) * v[j];
      }
    }
  }
  if( ! byrow ){
    for (int i = 0; i < m.nrow(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m.ncol(); j++) {
        out(i,j) = m(i,j) * v[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return out ;
}'

#  Make it available
cppFunction( func )

#  Use it
res1 <- mmult( m , v )

#  OP function
res2 <- mat %*% diag(v)

#  Same result?
identical( res1 , res2 ) # Yes!!
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is the intended behaviour of `mmult` to modify the original `m`? e.g., take a look at: `m <- m2 <- matrix(runif(9), nc=3); v <- 1:3; z <- mmult(m, v); identical(m, z); identical(m, m2)`. With double matrices, the original matrix is overwritten by the function's output! Some kind of pointer sorcery?

Comment: @jbaums let me get back to you... Not sure at the mo.

Comment: I don't really understand c++ very well, but if you use `NumericMatrix out(m.nrow(), m.ncol());`, the problem doesn't occur, but it slows things down a bit (approx 6 times as long for `mat` and `vec` given in the question).