# Multiplying a column vector by a numeric scalar in RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I am having some trouble compiling this simple `c++` code using `Rcpp` and the `RcppArmadillo` package. Take the following simple example to multiply each column of a matrix by a numeric scalar:

```
code <- 'arma::mat out = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(m);
for(int i = 0; i < out.n_cols; ++i){
  out.col(i) *= v;
}
return Rcpp::wrap( out );'
```

Trying to compile this using...

```
require( RcppArmadillo )
armMult <- cxxfunction( signature( m = "numeric" , v = "numeric" ),
                        code , plugin = "RcppArmadillo" )
```

Results in the compile error....

```
#error: no match for 'operator*=' in 'arma::Mat<eT>::col(arma::uword) [with eT = double, arma::uword = unsigned int](((unsigned int)i)) *= v'
```

However, if we swap the `numeric` variable `v` for `2.0` as below....

```
code <- 'arma::mat out = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(m);
for(int i = 0; i < out.n_cols; ++i){
  out.col(i) *= 2.0; //Notice we use 2.0 instead of a variable
}
return Rcpp::wrap( out );'
```

It compiles just fine....

```
armMult <- cxxfunction( signature(m="numeric"),
                        code,plugin="RcppArmadillo")
```

And we can then do...

```
m <- matrix( 1:4 , 2 , 2 )

armMult( m )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8
```

What am I missing here? How can I make this work with a simple numeric scalar. I would like to be able to pass a scalar like...

```
armMult( m , 2.0 )
```

And return the same result as above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to multiply each column of a matrix **A** by the corresponding element of a vector **x** then try this:

```
Rcpp:::cppFunction(
    "arma::mat fun(arma::mat A, arma::rowvec x) 
    { 
        A.each_row() %= x;
        return A;
    }", depends = "RcppArmadillo"
)

fun(matrix(rep(1, 6), 3, 2), c(5, 1))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    1
[2,]    5    1
[3,]    5    1
```

Comment: +1 Great answer! You should also leave that as an answer to [***this question***](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18349053/1478381).

Comment: Or if you aren't keen I will add it (with links and credit of course) into my answer and add to the benchmarks against other answers.

Comment: Sure! Go ahead and add it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I scratch my head over issues like this, I start by reducing the problem. Try a C++ three-liner just using Armadillo headers.  Make it work, then move it over to RcppArmadillo.

*Edit:* One can do better than your answer as you don't need to multiply each column individually (though one can).  Anyway, this just shows off *Rcpp Attributes*:

```
> cppFunction("arma::mat simon(arma::mat m, double v) { return m * v;}", 
+             depends="RcppArmadillo")
> simon(matrix(1:4,2,2), 3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    9
[2,]    6   12
>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your comment on the question helped this newbie a lot.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the edit. Actually, I guess I was taking a leaf out of your book and reducing the problem. What I actually want to do is multiply each column by each corresponding element of a vector (following [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18349053/1478381)), but I thought I would get this simpler example working first, but this solution is great to illustrate Rcpp attributes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment by @DirkEddelbuettel it was simply because I had not defined `v`...

```
code <- '
arma::mat out = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(m);
double scl = Rcpp::as<double>(v);
for(int i = 0; i < out.n_cols; ++i){
  out.col(i) *= scl;
}
return Rcpp::wrap( out );
'

armMult <- cxxfunction( signature( m = "numeric" , v = "numeric" ),
                        code , plugin = "RcppArmadillo" )

armMult( m , 2.0 )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8
```