# Python numpy or pandas equivalent of the R function sweep()

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, pandas

What is the `numpy` or `pandas` equivalent of the R function `sweep()`?

To elaborate: in R let's say we have a coefficient vector, say `beta`  (numeric type) and an array, say `data` (20x5 numeric type). I want to superimpose the vector on each row of the array and multiply the corresponding elements. And then return the resultant (20x5) array I could achieve this using `sweep()`.

Equivalent sample `R` code:

```
beta <-  c(10, 20, 30, 40)
data <- array(1:20,c(5,4))
sweep(data,MARGIN=2,beta,`*`)
#---------------
 > data
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    6   11   16
 [2,]    2    7   12   17
 [3,]    3    8   13   18
 [4,]    4    9   14   19
 [5,]    5   10   15   20

 > beta
 [1] 10 20 30 40

 > sweep(data,MARGIN=2,beta,`*`)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   10  120  330  640
 [2,]   20  140  360  680
 [3,]   30  160  390  720
 [4,]   40  180  420  760
 [5,]   50  200  450  800
```

I have heard exciting things about `numpy` and `pandas` in Python and it seems to have a lot of `R` like commands. What would be the fastest way to achieve the same using these libraries? The actual data has millions of rows and around 50 columns. The `beta` vector is of course conformable with data.

Comment: Since some knowledgeable pandas users might not have R installed, this question could be greatly improved by showing the inputs to and output from `sweep`

Comment: What is this MARGIN? docs are unclear on what difference is between just sweeping (i.e. `beta * data`).

Comment: MARGIN indicates whether to work on columns on rows, MARGIN=2 means columns and 1 means rows

Comment: It's a lot easier to see what is happening if the numbers are not random. Hence my edit.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643555/multiply-rows-of-matrix-by-vector

Comment: It would require a bit of fiddling but `vstack` and e.g. `for i in range(1,6): out = i*array([10, 20, 30, 40])` should do the trick.

Comment: @infominer Are you sure that's the case? the r docs suggest it's more subtle... if that is the case the docs here are *terrible*.

Comment: @AndyHayden. Yes I am sure. `sweep` is based on `apply`. if you read the documentation for apply, the definition is amply clear IMHO. Before you ask, yes apply is mentioned on the docs page for sweep (look under see also).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas has an ***`apply()`*** method too, apply being what R's *`sweep()`* uses under the hood. (Note that the MARGIN argument is "equivalent" to the `axis` argument in many pandas functions, except that it [takes values 0 and 1 rather than 1 and 2](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)).

```
np.random.seed = 1    
beta = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))    
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 5))
```

You can use an apply with a function which is called on each row:

```
data.apply(lambda row: row * beta, axis=1)
```

*Note: that `axis=0` would apply to each column, this is the default as data is stored column-wise and so column-wise operations are more efficient.*

However, in this case it's easy to make **significantly faster** (and more readable) to vectorize, simply by multiplying row-wise:

```
In [21]: data.apply(lambda row: row * beta, axis=1).head()
Out[21]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.024827 -1.465294 -0.416155 -0.369182 -0.649587
1  0.026433  0.355915 -0.672302  0.225446 -0.520374
2  0.042254 -1.223200 -0.545957  0.103864 -0.372855
3  0.086367  0.218539 -1.033671  0.218388 -0.598549
4  0.203071 -3.402876  0.192504 -0.147548 -0.726001

In [22]: data.mul(beta, axis=1).head()  # just show first few rows with head
Out[22]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.024827 -1.465294 -0.416155 -0.369182 -0.649587
1  0.026433  0.355915 -0.672302  0.225446 -0.520374
2  0.042254 -1.223200 -0.545957  0.103864 -0.372855
3  0.086367  0.218539 -1.033671  0.218388 -0.598549
4  0.203071 -3.402876  0.192504 -0.147548 -0.726001
```

*Note: this is slightly more robust / allows more control than using `*`.*

You can do the same in numpy (ie `data.values` here), either multiplying directly, this will be faster as it doesn't worry about data-alignment, or using [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) rather than apply.

Comment: Great answer. I am playing around with this approach now and had a question. Can you please comment on the use of `lambda` in `apply`? Any reason to prefer it over a function declared using `def`? Thanks much.

Comment: It's just an anonymous function, there's not reason to prefer it (other than pleasing/concise syntax)!

Answer (score 4):

In numpy the concept is called "broadcasting". Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((4, 3))
x * np.array(range(4))[:, np.newaxis] # sweep along the rows
x + np.array(range(3))[np.newaxis, :] # sweep along the columns
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work faster?

```
t(t(data) * beta)
```

Some other great answers here with profiling [Multiply rows of matrix by vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643555/multiply-rows-of-matrix-by-vector)

and finally to answer your query about numpy. Use this reference (search for Matrix Multiplication)
http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html

Comment: Yes, edited to included a reference to equivalent calls in numpy.
and suggested my code as a workaround for speed issues as sweep is slow for matrix multiplication. The O.P can look at my linked answer to see run times.