# How does the R sweep function work with a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand the way sweep function works with multidimensional arrays(4d, 5d ...) specifically when margin equals tuple of dims c(1,2), c(1,3) ...

for example:

```
x<-array(1,dim = c(2,3,4,5))
sweep(x, STATS=_, MARGIN= c(1,2), FUN='*')
```

What should the dimensions of STATS here?
and how it works?

Comment: Could you please further explain what you mean by **What should the dimensions of STATS here?**?

Comment: I mean what the acceptable dimensions will work without warnings "Correct Dimensions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of the statistics given in `STATS` should be the same as the dimensions resulting from `MARGIN`alizing the data in the input array or, although not recommended, a size that is a sub-multiple of the number of elements in that result (e.g. length 2 in a 2x3 array; or a 2x4 array in a 2x4x3 array; or 2x2 array in a 2x4x3 array, etc.).

In order to understand the dimensions resulting from `MARGIN`alizing the data, let's look at an example:

```
# Example data in a 3D array of size 2x3x4
set.seed(1717)
x = array(runif(2*3*4), c(2,3,4))

# We MARGINalize the data by computing the mean on all dimensions *other than*
# the stated ones: (1, 3)
# This gives a 2D result whose dimension is of size
# "length of dim 1" x "length of dim 3", i.e. 2x4
marginalize_on_dims = c(1,3)
m = apply(x, marginalize_on_dims, mean)
```

which results in the following 2x4 "means" array:

```
> m
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.3662613 0.2971481 0.155660 0.5121214
[2,] 0.5808111 0.7322553 0.662044 0.4984720
```

We now sweep out the computed means `m` from the original `x` array:

```
x_swept_out_of_means_m = sweep(x, STATS=m, MARGIN=marginalize_on_dims)
```

which results in:

```
> x_swept_out_of_means_m
, , 1

           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.2934119 -0.3224825 0.6158943
[2,] -0.4540748  0.1814070 0.2726678

, , 2

           [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.1452443 0.3631910 -0.21794673
[2,] -0.1205201 0.0873856  0.03313448

, , 3

              [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.0766162667 -0.14700413  0.22362039
[2,]  0.0006661599  0.05828265 -0.05894881

, , 4

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.2341822 -0.4071083  0.1729261
[2,] -0.2680816  0.4772658 -0.2091843
```

We now note that the summary on the swept-out result shows a mean of `0` which is consistent to having substracted the mean:

```
> summary(x_swept_out_of_means_m)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.45407 -0.21137 -0.02914  0.00000  0.19196  0.61589
```

Therefore in your example, since you are marginalizing on dimensions 1 and 2, you should use a `STATS` value that is of dimension 2x3, for instance:

```
x <- array(1, dim=c(2,3,4,5))
sweep(x, STATS=matrix(nrow=c(2,3), data=c(2,3,-2,4,0,-3)), MARGIN=c(1,2), FUN='*')
```

where the result should be a 2x3x4x5 array with the following 2x3 array repeated 4x5 times:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   -2    0
[2,]    3    4   -3
```

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you think there is an equivalent for sweep in python or even most close to it?

Comment: There should be... using Python's broadcasting. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117756/python-numpy-or-pandas-equivalent-of-the-r-function-sweep