# How to do elementwise multiplication of big matrix with vector very fast?

Tags: r

I want to do elementwise multiplication of a vector with every rows of a very big binary matrix. length of my vector is equal to number of columns of my matrix. I have implemented using for loop as follow, but it's very slow.
Does anyone knows solution to speed it up?

```
A <- c()
M # Binary matric
W <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(M), ncol=ncol(M))
W <- data.frame(W)
for (i in 1:nrow(W)) {
    W[i,] <- M[i,] * A
}
```

Comment: Turning `W` into a data.frame is a mistake. AFAIK, matrix subassignment is faster than data.frame subassignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vector recycling, Since matrices are filled by columns, you need to transpose:

```
t(t(M) * v)
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is certainly not the fastest way to do this on R. This is significantly faster, I don't know if it is the fastest way:

```
M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v)
```

Note also a C/C++ based solution to this problem for both matrices and data frames is provided by `collapse::TRA` (which in addition supports grouped sweeping operations). Benckmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(collapse)

all_obj_equal(t(t(M) * v), M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), TRA(M, v, "*"))
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(t(t(M) * v), M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), TRA(M, v, "*"), times = 100, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
                                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
                          t(t(M) * v) 16.256563 12.703469 10.771698 12.113859 10.148008 8.365288   100   c
   M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v)  1.097177  1.449713  1.375522  1.426085  1.273911 1.785404   100  b 
                       TRA(M, v, "*")  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100 a
```

(Note: M here is the [Eora 26 ICIO Matrix 2015](https://www.worldmrio.com/eora26/) of Dimension 4915 x 4915, v is 1/output)

**2022 Update**

I found that `tcrossprod()` is often a bit faster than `outer()`, especially for smaller data since it is `.Internal` whereas outer has some R overhead. Regarding package solutions, *collapse* now introduced operators `%r*%` etc. to do this effectively, and also the `setop` function and operators `%+=%` etc. to preform math by reference. Thus here a new benchmark on generated data, showing that C-level math by reference is an order or magnitude faster than efficient base R for this particular problem.

```r
library(collapse) # 1.8+
library(Rfast)
library(microbenchmark)
M <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000) # 1000 x 1000 matrix
v <- rnorm(1000)              # 1000 x 1 vector

# Testing numeric equality of methods
all_obj_equal(t(t(M) * v),
              M %r*% v, 
              M * tcrossprod(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), 
              M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), 
              eachrow(M, v, "*"), 
              setop(M, "*", v, rowwise = TRUE))
#> [1] TRUE

# Undo modification by reference
setop(M, "/", v, rowwise = TRUE)

# Benchmark
microbenchmark(collapse_ref = setop(M, "*", v, rowwise = TRUE),
               collapse_ref_rev = setop(M, "/", v, rowwise = TRUE), # Need to reverse operation by reference each iteration
               collapse_op = M %r*% v, 
               tcrossprod = M * tcrossprod(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), 
               outer = M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v), 
               Rfast = eachrow(M, v, "*"), times = 10000)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>              expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq        max neval
#>      collapse_ref  167.731  185.8530  310.1048  212.175  317.3605  16423.616 10000
#>  collapse_ref_rev  188.272  205.4510  323.1454  231.527  326.1960   7483.115 10000
#>       collapse_op  183.926  925.7595 1794.6258 1157.738 1666.4040  59253.815 10000
#>        tcrossprod 1107.779 1959.0005 3118.5997 2324.700 3302.3040 182811.579 10000
#>             outer 1112.904 1981.9195 3096.3271 2345.200 3298.9215  90762.766 10000
#>             Rfast  178.432  925.1445 1886.5011 1151.710 1703.3655 103405.239 10000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Rfast::eachrow` wich is quite fast.

```
M<-Rfast::matrnorm(1000,1000)
v=rnorm(1000)

Rfast2::benchmark(Rfast::eachrow(M,v,"*"),M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v),M * Rfast::Outer(v, rep.int(1, nrow(M))),times = 100)
   milliseconds 
                                            min      mean      max
Rfast::eachrow(M, v, "*")                2.4790  4.440305  12.3601
M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v)       5.7612 25.952871 807.1748
M * Rfast::Outer(v, rep.int(1, nrow(M))) 3.4185  7.525743 204.3348
```

Comment: The output of `Rfast::Outer` is a transposed version of the matrix produced by the regular `outer` function, so you have to use `M*t(Rfast::Outer(rep.int(1,nrow(M)),v))`.

Comment: Yes you are correct but you don't have to transposed the result. Just flip the ```Rfast::Outer``` arguments and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Some other *base* options might be.

```
sweep(M, 2, v, `*`)
M * v[col(M)]
M * rep(v, each=nrow(M))
M * matrix(v, nrow(M), ncol(M), TRUE)
```

Benchmark for *base* options.

```
METHODS <- alist(
rep    = M * rep(v, each=nrow(M)),
tt     = t(t(M) * v),
sweep  = sweep(M, 2, v, `*`),
col    = M * v[col(M)],
matrix = M * matrix(v, nrow(M), ncol(M), TRUE),
outer  = M * outer(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v),
tcrosp = M * tcrossprod(rep.int(1L, nrow(M)), v)  )

set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000)
v <- M[1,]
bench::mark(exprs = METHODS)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 rep        15.86ms 15.96ms      61.7    7.63MB     15.4    24     6      389ms
#2 tt          5.02ms  5.45ms     173.    15.26MB     78.5    55    25      319ms
#3 sweep       5.62ms  5.93ms     155.    15.29MB     71.3    48    22      309ms
#4 col            4ms  4.24ms     214.    11.45MB     75.5    71    25      331ms
#5 matrix       2.9ms  3.15ms     306.     7.63MB     53.3   115    20      376ms
#6 outer       1.67ms  2.65ms     373.     7.67MB     66.8   145    26      389ms
#7 tcrosp      1.67ms  2.64ms     369.     7.64MB     66.3   139    25      377ms

set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 100000)
v <- M[1,]
bench::mark(exprs = METHODS)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 rep        15.88ms 15.92ms      62.7    7.63MB     12.1    26     5      415ms
#2 tt          5.39ms  6.07ms     166.    15.26MB     75.1    53    24      319ms
#3 sweep       6.08ms  6.32ms     156.    15.26MB     78.1    44    22      282ms
#4 col         3.25ms  3.32ms     298.    11.44MB     95.3    97    31      325ms
#5 matrix      2.25ms  2.29ms     433.     7.63MB     79.0   159    29      367ms
#6 outer       1.82ms  1.89ms     520.     8.77MB    118.    177    40      340ms
#7 tcrosp      1.81ms  1.88ms     495.     8.77MB    106.    173    37      349ms

set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 10)
v <- M[1,]
bench::mark(exprs = METHODS)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 rep        15.88ms 15.94ms      62.4    7.63MB     12.0    26     5      417ms
#2 tt          5.39ms  6.08ms     164.    15.26MB     74.4    53    24      322ms
#3 sweep       4.12ms  4.22ms     223.    15.26MB     76.3    73    25      328ms
#4 col         4.02ms  4.17ms     234.    11.44MB     49.1    86    18      367ms
#5 matrix      4.11ms  4.39ms     227.     7.63MB     28.0    97    12      428ms
#6 outer       2.02ms  2.11ms     423.     7.63MB     59.0   172    24      407ms
#7 tcrosp      2.03ms  2.12ms     419.     7.63MB     56.5   163    22      389ms
```

Even for a 1e6 matrix the used times are some ms. In cases this operation is done very often it will matter.