# How can I improve a simple subtraction in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix

I want to substract a vector (`S_0`) from every row of a matrix (`S_t`). Unfortunately, calculating my for loop takes so much time as the number of rows is 1 million.

```
i <- 1
n <- 1000000

X_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 10))

for (i in i:n) {
  X_t[i,] <- S_t[i, ] - S_0 
}
```

`S_0` is a vector of length 10

`S_t` is a data frame of dimension n x 10 containing values from prior calculations

My first idea was to transform `S_0` into a matrix of dimension `n x 10` (all rows are identical then). Maybe it's faster to substract a matrix from a matrix? Unfortunately, I could not find out how to do this effeciently without using another for loop.

Furthermore, I tried this:

`data.frame(matrix(S_0, nrow = n, ncol = 10))`

but the output was not what I expected as the order of the numbers was mixed up within every row.

Comment: Do you want a `data.frame` or a `matrix` as result?

Comment: `data.frame` is fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327572/9463489

Answer (score 2):

You can use `col` to transpose the vector and keepe the type of `S_t`

```
X_t <- S_t - S_0[col(S_t)]
```

```
S_0 <- 1:10
S_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 10))

X_t <- S_t - S_0[col(S_t)]

X_t
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
#2 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
#3 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
#4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
#5 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10

str(X_t)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  10 variables:
# $ X1 : num  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
# $ X2 : num  -2 -2 -2 -2 -2
# $ X3 : num  -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
# $ X4 : num  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4
# $ X5 : num  -5 -5 -5 -5 -5
# $ X6 : num  -6 -6 -6 -6 -6
# $ X7 : num  -7 -7 -7 -7 -7
# $ X8 : num  -8 -8 -8 -8 -8
# $ X9 : num  -9 -9 -9 -9 -9
# $ X10: num  -10 -10 -10 -10 -10
```

```
S_t <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 10)
X_t <- S_t - S_0[col(S_t)]
str(X_t)
# num [1:5, 1:10] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 ...
```

---

Another option is using `sweep`, also keeping the type.

```
sweep(S_t, 2, S_0)
```

---

Another option is using `Map`.

```
Map(`-`, S_t, S_0) #Returning list

list2DF(Map(`-`, S_t, S_0)) #Returning data.frame

do.call(cbind, Map(`-`, S_t, S_0)) #Returning matrix
```

---

Benchmark (thanks to @Maël for the template)

```
S_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 1000000, ncol = 10))
S_0 <- 1:10

bench::mark(check = FALSE, iterations = 10,
tt = t(t(S_t) - S_0),
col = S_t - S_0[col(S_t)], 
sweep = sweep(S_t, 2, S_0),
Map = Map(`-`, S_t, S_0),
MapDf = list2DF(Map(`-`, S_t, S_0)),
MapMatr = do.call(cbind, Map(`-`, S_t, S_0))
)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 tt          96.1ms  98.6ms      9.92   228.9MB     4.96    10     5      1.01s
#2 col        282.9ms 310.4ms      3.28   509.5MB     7.55    10    23      3.04s
#3 sweep      312.9ms 314.1ms      3.18   547.6MB     6.36    10    20      3.15s
#4 Map           13ms    19ms     53.6     76.3MB    26.8     10     5   186.54ms
#5 MapDf         13ms  20.3ms     48.0     76.3MB    14.4     10     3    208.5ms
#6 MapMatr     23.2ms    25ms     37.8    152.6MB    26.4     10     7   264.76ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `t` twice:

```r
S_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 1000000, ncol = 10))
S_0 <- 1:10

X_t <- t(t(S_t) - S_0)

# > head(X_t)
#      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# [1,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
# [2,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
# [3,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
# [4,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
# [5,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
# [6,] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
```

---

Benchmark: `t` is the fastest

```r
bench::mark(t(t(S_t) - S_0),
            S_t - S_0[col(S_t)], 
            sweep(S_t, 2, S_0),
            check = FALSE, iterations = 10)
#  expression               min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr
#1 t(t(S_t) - S_0)        211ms   321ms    3.10   229MB    2.17    10
#2 S_t - S_0[col(S_t)]    691ms   874ms    1.13   509MB    1.82    10
#3 sweep(S_t, 2, S_0)     638ms   735ms    1.34   548MB    2.54    10
```

Comment: great! Thank you! Now I have a better understanding how R handles matrices and vectors in + / - operations!